# SessionStorage only works with one browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, session-storage

This is my first time working with SessionStorage. I have an ASP.NET Web App, using MVC pattern. And I have a view that uses 2 different modals, one for Create and the other one for Edit, modals work perfectly.

Now, I'm using sessionStorage to save the id of the element the user edited, then using on window.onload change the row color to red.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Save').click(function () {
            var Idval = document.getElementById("id").value;
            sessionStorage.setItem("idSession", Idval);
        });


        window.onload = function () {
            let sessionval = sessionStorage.getItem("idSession");
            document.getElementById(sessionval).bgColor = '#FF0000';
        };
    });
```

The problem is, this code works only with the browser where I have my Gmail account opened (Idk if that makes sense to you, but that's what I realize), but if I try in another browser or when I Compile the project it just doesn't work

Do you have any idea about what could be happening?

Comment: SessionStorage gets cleared whenever you recompile/open in another browser. Is there a reason why you're not using LocalStorage, where you have much more explicit control over the lifecycle?

Comment: I know, what I mean is, in the browser where I don't have my gmail account, doesn't work even the first time. I'm no triying to use the same sessionStorage between browsers, I just want to use it in one session